# what is the purpose of rsync's -a flag

Tags: linux, rsync

So ive read the manual searched google, but not enough information on what is really the purpose of this rsync's `-a` flag

the manual says to provide *archive*. is it the same archive as in `tar`?

i just can't assume directly so i have to ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

So `-a` is just shorthand for `-rlptgoD`, which are typical settings for all the commonly used options when syncing from one file system to another.

In general use `rsync -a ...` unless you have something specific you need to do differently.

Comment: hey, do you also happen to know how to enable partial transfer? thanks agian

Comment: Yes, it's right there on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync): `--partial               keep partially transferred files`. So it would just be: `rsync -a --partial ...`.

Comment: `cp` has `cp -a` too (not saying it's an exact match)  archive just means 'transfer a lot of permissions and other filesystem meta data over from source'.  If you don't need permissions etc copied over just use `-r` (merely recurse into directories) permissions of existing files in destination will be preserved.  RTM `r`,`l`,`p`,`t`,`g`,`o`,`D` for what your missing out on (IMO there in order of usefulness).